# how to set audience for a client registration spring-authorization-server

Tags: spring, spring-security, access-token, spring-authorization-server

hello I'm using spring authorization server version 0.3.1, and I'm trying to define the audience for the generated tokens. It seems that the default behavior is spring setting the client-id as the audience, i'm looking for a way to have a different audience than the client-id

Comment: You should upgrade to 1.1.1.  Regardless, this is still the same.

Comment: Have you tried using [OAuth2TokenCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer)?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/15835039/steve-riesenberg

I was able to specify an audience with the following code:

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<OAuth2TokenClaimsContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
          context.getClaims().audience(Collections.singletonList("my-audience"));
        };
    }
```